# Strange exception after OnActivate event in Caliburn Micro on Windows Phone 7.x

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, webclient, caliburn.micro

I have some trouble with activating ViewModel.
That situation:

I have ViewModel with property that load data from internet if field is null:

```
private string _content;
public string Content {
  get {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_content)) {
      LoadBody();
      _content = Localization.AppResources.LOADING;
    }
    return _content;
  }
  set {
    if (value != _content) {
      _content = value;
      NotifyOfPropertyChange("Content");
    }
  }
}

private void LoadBody() {
  try {
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
    wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(String.Format("http://www.diffbot.com/api/article?token={0}&summary=1&url={1}", diffbotToken, this._note.url)));
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
  }
}
```

Before loading complete I press Windows button. I see my home screen

Than I press Back button. But my app crashes without any message after OnActivate method executes.

Can anybody help me? What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot remove [DataMember] attribute from my class. After removing all goes okey.